# Not able to get desired out on php page through mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I don't enter or enter any random info in search, result shows, "No Results Found" And I am okay with that but when I enter anything related to MySQL table shows error,

> "**Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_assocc() in /home/opticfhb/public_html/vacationsbychoice.com/search_result.php on line 10".

I know page is able to connect to db.

Form:

```
<form name="form_search" method="post" action="search_result.php">
    <input name="search" id="search" type="text" value="Type the name of City, State or Place you are visiting.." onFocus="if (value == 'Type the name of City, State or Place you are visiting..') {value=''}" onBlur="if (value== '') {value='Type the name of City, State or Place you are visiting..'}" />

    <input id="from" type="date" value="Check In" onFocus="if (value == 'Check In') {value=''}" onBlur="if (value== '') {value='Check In'}" />

    <input id="to" type="date" value="Check Out" onFocus="if (value == 'Check Out') {value=''}" onBlur="if (value== '') {value='Check Out'}" />

    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(!isset($_POST['search'])) {
header("Location:index.php");
}

$search_sql="SELECT * FROM world_wise WHERE stat_province LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%' or city LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'";

$search_query=mysql_query($search_sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($search_query)!=0) {
    $search_rs=mysql_fetch_assocc($search_query);
}

?>
```

Result:

```
<h2>Search Result</h2>
<?php if (mysql_num_rows($search_query)!=0) {
do { ?>

<p><?php echo $search_rs['name']; ?></p>

<?php   } while ($search_rs=mysql_fetch_assocc($search_query));

} else {
echo "No Results Found";

}
?>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assocc`. `assoc` **not** `assocc`

Comment: As stated above, you're using an invalid mysql syntax. Also why is there a closing curly brace just before the `while` loop in `<?php   } while`

Comment: I've also noticed that and will wait for OP to tell us. @asprin Edit: The OP's question has been edited and it now shows the "why". The question's code must have been improperly indented.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. Yes I got it fixed, moreover I am gonna use error reporting to. It was stupid me. New to php.

Comment: You're welcome @Sebastian do read what I have in my answer though.

Comment: I have got this strange problem now where it says,"Notice: Undefined index: name in /home/opticfhb/public_html/vacationsbychoice.com/search_result.php on line 226"
For demo please visit www.vacationsbychoice.com and enter winter in search. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple; change both instances of `mysql_fetch_assocc` to `mysql_fetch_assoc` (a typo)
There are 2x `c`'s instead of one at the end of the function's name.

Use error reporting at the top of your files when in production mode.

`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

---

**Footnotes:**

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo).

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Comment: wew, you got fast fingers XD

Comment: I type at about 90wpm ;-) @ICanHasCheezburger

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a simple typo: `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, not `mysql_fetch_assocc()`.

Comment: I have got this strange problem now where it says,"Notice: Undefined index: name in /home/opticfhb/public_html/vacationsbychoice.com/search_result.php on line 226"
For demo please visit www.vacationsbychoice.com and enter winter in search. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see you are using wrong mysql function mysql_fetch_assocc, its mysql_fetch_assoc

```
if(!isset($_POST['search'])) {
header("Location:index.php");
}   
$search_sql="SELECT * FROM world_wise WHERE stat_province LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%' or city LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'";
$search_query=mysql_query($search_sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($search_query)!=0) {
$search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query);
}
?>
```

If you are not sure about the functions you are using , try to put debug mode on , in short make error_reporting ON always to display errors